# Can we install sharepoint server 2013 in window 8?

Tags: 2013, configuration

I am bit confused about SharePoint installation. Is there a way to install SharePoint on Windows 8. Because I searched google and some experts are saying we can install and someone are against this.

For SharePoint installation, is windows 2000 server needed or we can install it within Windows 8 itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not recommended to install SharePoint 2013 directly on a client operating system like Windows 8. It has to be installed on a Server Operating System like Windows Server 2008 R2 or Windows Server 2012.

If you want to install on Windows 8, I suggest you use Hyper-V which comes by default in Windows 8 and install your SharePoint 2013 in a virtual machine running on top of Windows 8.

Comment: nice explanation.

Comment: hi vardhaman sir, what is the best way?  I want to be a sharepoint administrator.shall I need to complete certification or??

Comment: Google is your best friend. You should find a lot of articles on the same topic.

Comment: What is Hyper-v, would you describe with more words. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can install SharePoint 2013 on Windows 8 using this tool, you decide if it's a good fit for you :-)

http://www.disruptivei.com/Blogg/Inl%C3%A4gg/6/Install-SharePoint-2013-on-Windows-7-8-8-1

Thanks,
Jonas

Answer (score 0):

If you need to yes, you can with the link below. 
http://www.guideushow.com/sharepoint/install-sharepoint-2013-on-windows-7-8-and-8-1/

**but this is not supported at all by microsoft and should only be considered as a last resort**